# ObjC generic collection with protocol as parameter is translated as [AnyObject]

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, language-interoperability

Why `protocols` property is translated as [AnyObject] in swift, not as [P]

```
@protocol P;
@class C;

@interface TestGenerics: NSObject

@property  NSArray<C*>* classes;
@property NSArray<P>* protocols;

@end
```

In Swift it look this way:

```
public class TestGenerics : NSObject {

    public var classes: [C]
    public var protocols: [AnyObject]
}
```

UPDATE: Found solution

```
@property NSArray<NSObject<P>*>* protocols;
```

or like suggested newacct

```
@property NSArray<id<P>>* protocols;
```

is translated to:

```
public var protocols: [P]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`P` is not a type in Objective-C. `id<P>` is an Objective-C type type for anything that conforms to the protocol `P`. (`NSObject<P> *` is a type for anything that is an instance of `NSObject` *and* conforms to the protocol `P`, which is slightly different condition.)

So the best way to write it would be:

```
@property NSArray<id<P>> *protocols;
```

Comment: Does apple say anywhere that protocol parameter in generic does not affect type of array in Swift

Comment: It works for `NSArray`, but if you use `NSSet<id<P> > *protocols` you'll get `Set<AnyHashable>`.